# S3 Access Denied when specify the principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-denied, principal

Bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456784337:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456784337:user/lambda-user"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
   }
```

Initialize

```
 AWS.config.update({
      region: 'ap-southeast-1',
      accessKey: 'abcxxxx',
      secretAccessKey:'abcdxxx'

    });
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
     IdentityPoolId: 'ap-southeast-1:12340000-5587-4d40-91fe-9fab5668c708'
    });
```

S3 getObject

```
function (bucketName, key) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key,
  };
  return s3.getObject(params).promise()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Successfully read from S3!');
      return data;
    });
};
```

Congnito userUnauthenticated

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Failed to read to S3. AccessDenied: Access Denied
(node:73168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AccessDenied: Access Denied

It only works when Principal is wildcard but it is not advisable to have that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the policy to read files from S3.

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1528709447655",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "Stmt1528709412334",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        ],
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123456784337:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::487686674337:user/lambda-user"
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks but got Error: Missing required principal

Comment: In just gave the policy to a role, we need to add the principals in it. :) Anwer updated.

Comment: Still errorFailed to read to S3. AccessDenied: Access Denied
(node:73208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AccessDenied: Access Denied                                                                                 What is wrong there? Do I  need to create authenticated user in Cognito?

Comment: I have the cognito for unauthenticated policy. I updated the problem use case above. Thanks

Comment: I just updated the policy, it worked for me(Im not tested with Cognito, but an IAM user). So try this. Or Refer here: https://blog.powerupcloud.com/share-files-securely-over-internet-using-aws-cognito-and-s3-126811991d23

Comment: it still doesn't work. I am actually accessing the s3 from nodejs code. I already set up the IAM user  and put in bucket policy to restrict the access of s3 from public. But it doesn't work.  Do you have skype? Can I screenshare to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172880/discussion-between-scott-jones-and-sqladmin).